# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}K(x)^2\text{d}x -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2} }{2-x^2}K(x)^2\text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Recently, I found this identity on a mathematical site(seems true):

> $$\int_{0}^{1}K(x)^2\text{d}x
> -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2} }{2-x^2}K(x)^2\text{d}x
> =\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )^4 }{64}$$
> where $K(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-x^2t^2}  }\text{d}t$.

A problem that resemble the above identity is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395085/). Which has the power $3$. But so far, I still don't really know how to relate those two integrals.

Comment: Are you asking here for a proof of the given identity?

Answer (score 7):

To calculate this integral we can utilize the following Ramanujan identity:

$$\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dy=\frac{2}{1+x}K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)\tag{*}$$

This is found as eq. $(42)$ in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1735) article by Yajun Zhou (and proven a bit later).

---

In order to be able to apply the above identity, we'll start similarly to @Miracle Invoker's answer by applying some substitutions alongside Landen's Transformation (LT) to the second integral.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}K^2(x)}{2-x^2}dx\overset{1-x^2\to x^2}=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}K^2(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$$

$$\overset{LT}=4\int_0^1 \frac{x^2K^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{(1+x^2)(1+x)^2}dx\overset{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\to x}=\int_0^1 K^2(x)\left(1-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx $$

---

Plugging this into the original integral yields:

$$\int_0^1 K^2(x)dx-\int_0^1 \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}K^2(x)}{2-x^2}dx\overset{x^2\to x}=\int_0^1 \frac{K^2(\sqrt x)}{1+x}dx$$

$$\overset{\large x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}{1+x}dx\overset{\large (*)}=\frac12\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dydx$$

$$=\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \int_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dxdy=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy =\boxed{\frac{\Gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{64}}$$

Where the last integral can be found evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605552/515527) as:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy = \int_0^1 \frac{K(y)}{\sqrt y}dy =\frac12 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt y\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)^2=\frac{\Gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{16\pi}$$

Comment: +1 Nice and elegant solution.

Comment: @User thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer.

---

$$I=\int_0^1K^2dk-\int_0^1\frac{kk'}{2-k^2}K^2dk$$

Well as far as I have seen Closed Form of the First Integral is not known, so our first step should be to remove the same term from the second integral such that both cancel out.

Using $k\to k'$ on the Second Integral we have,
$$\int_0^1\frac{kk'}{2-k^2}K^2dk=\int_0^1K'^2dk-\int_0^1\frac{K'^2}{1+k^2}dk$$

Using Landen's Transformation on the Integral of $K'^2$ we get,

$$K\left[\frac{1-k}{1+k}\right]=\left(\frac{1+k}{2}\right)K'$$

$$\int_0^1K'^2dk=2\int_0^1K^2dk$$

Use it again on the Second Integral we get,

$$\int_0^1\frac{K'^2}{1+k^2}dk=\int_0^1K^2dk+2\int_0^1\frac{kK^2}{1+k^2}dk$$

So finally we obtain,

$$I=2\int_0^1\frac{kK^2}{1+k^2}dk$$

Using Theorem 1 Equation $(15)$ from [MOMENTS OF PRODUCTS OF ELLIPTIC INTEGRALS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1132.pdf) and setting $t=i$ results in,

$$\int_0^1\frac{kKK'}{1+k^2}dk=\frac{\Gamma^4(1/4)}{128}$$

Now we just need to prove that both of these Integrals are equal.

$$0=\int_0^1\frac{k}{1+k^2}[KK'-K^2]dk$$

I am having trouble in this part.

Comment: While proving that equality might not be easy (or at least not obvious), it is worth mentioning that by utilizing $(15)$ again and combining it with this question, yields a beautiful result:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x \ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2} K(x) K'(x)dx= \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{128} \left(\ln 2 - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

I'd say this would be quite hard to prove directly, without reverse engineering.

Comment: @Zacky Interestingly I had tried and arrived at the same!
As you seem well informed about Elliptic Integrals, I was wondering has anyone written a survey on them with recent advancements, like the papers from James Wan and Yajun Zhou.

Comment: I'm definitely not that well informed about Elliptic integrals- I just picked them up not long ago. And unfortunately, as far as I know there's no such survey. Currently those 3 papers seems to be the most useful ones: [Elliptic integral evaluations of Bessel moments](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0891);; [Moments of Products of Elliptic Integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1132);; [Legendre Functions, Spherical Rotations, and Multiple Elliptic Integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1735).
Of course MSE itself is really useful to search on, since it already has plenty of identities.

Comment: +1 for sure ...